# Null Pointer Exception when @EJB bean called

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb

This is my Servlet

```
//this is the url servlet
        @WebServlet("/CRUDServlet")

        public class CRUDServlet extends HttpServlet {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //this gives me problem
            @EJB
            private CRUD crud;

            public CRUDServlet() {
                super();
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            // GET METHOD
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                //The problem is here because when I call create the program gives me Null Pointer
                crud.create(new Home("Parigi", 100,00));
                response.getWriter().println("Hello friend!");
            }
        }
```

The Bean is a session bean stateless:

```
    @Stateless
    public class CRUDBean implements CRUD {


        @PersistenceContext(name="crudPersistence")
        private EntityManager em;

        public CRUDBean() {}

        @Override
        public void create(OggettoDaVendere o) {
            em.persist(o);
            return;
        }
    ...
    }
```

and when I go to local url: `http://localhost:8080/Example/CRUDServlet` it gives me null pointer exception and I don't know why. Anyone can help me?

> lug 11, 2018 4:32:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet.CRUDServlet] in
>   context with path [/EsercizioCRUD] threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   servlet.CRUDServlet.doGet(CRUDServlet.java:46)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Please, add a stack trace to the question

Comment: GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet.CRUDServlet] in context with path [/Example] threw exception
            java.lang.NullPointerException
             at servlet.CRUDServlet.doGet(CRUDServlet.java:46)
             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
             at

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)

Comment: You should edit you post to add those information, do not post it in comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Lorelorelore I have update the error stack!

Comment: Which one is row 46?

Comment: yes is the row where crud.create(new Home("Parigi", 100,00));. It seems that @EJB is not work

Comment: What does your build environment look like? EJB's are not supported by Tomcat out of the box - they require a decent amount more to work.

Comment: Create object and check  crud =new CRUD ();

Comment: Try using [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/) instead, it is meant for easy replacement of TomCat who want EE feature like `CDI` and `EJB`